# jquery code is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-mobile, codeigniter-2

I have a order form and before submitting order, user will have to go through captcha code for cash on delivery...

I am checking whether captcha code is right or wrong using jQuery.

If captcha code entered was wrong i won't let user submit form using preventDefault and will alert about error. But after entered captcha code right, It still doesn't let user submit the order.

Here is my code...

```
//for captcha code
      var captcha = null;
      //check if captcha code is right
      $("#apply_captcha").on("click", function(){
        var captchaUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/checkout/check_captcha/';
        var captcha = $('#userCaptcha').val(); //user entered value for captcha
          $.ajax({
                url: captchaUrl,
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'captcha='+captcha,
                success: function(result)
                {
                    if(result === "success")
                    {
                        captcha = true;
                        $('#captcha_msg').hide();
                        $('#userCaptcha').css('border', '2px solid green');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        captcha = false;
                        $('#captcha_msg').text("Sorry, Your captcha is wrong.");
                        $('#captcha_msg').css('color', '#cb2700');
                    }
                }
            });
      });

      $('#orderform').submit(function(e)
      {
          if(!pincode_available)
          {
              alert("Sorry, We are not supplying any product at this area right now.");
              e.preventDefault();
          }
          else if(!captcha)
          {
              alert("Sorry, Your captcha is wrong");
              e.preventDefault();
          }
      });
```

Comment: Do you have the code that checks the captcha?

Comment: @Kiran.B yeah... everything works fine.. if i enter the correct captch, border of input box will be green and in case of wrong captch it will show that msg too..
But problem happens when i submit the form... it checks captcha variable that i made global...

Comment: Can you check if on submit of the form, control goes into the function?

Comment: @Kiran.B No.. when i submitted the form it will only check those two if & else codition for pincode and captcha...
So it's not going into the function.. i have checked by using alert

Comment: try removing the keyword 'var' on line 6. looks like its creating a local variable whereas the submit function is using the global variable.

Comment: @Kiran.B ohh thanks.. that worked.. :) :)

Comment: Great! I created an answer. Perhaps you can accept that answer so it might help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the var keyword for the 'captcha' variable in the 'click' function. Looks like its creating a new local variable while the submit function is using the global variable.

P.S: Please see the comments on the question to see how we arrived at the solution.